# Recursion pseudocode with two values per function

Tags: algorithm, recursion, pseudocode

I am looking at this problem and I think it is a recursion problem.
 The two values (arguments), rather than one, for each function is what I am having trouble with.

// precondition: n and k are nonnegative integers

```
int f(int n, int k)

    if (k * n == 0) 
        return 1 
    else 
        return f(n - 1, k - 1) + f(n - 1, k) 
    end if 
end f
```

What value is returned by the call f(4, 2) ?

I have searched pretty extensively and am drawing a blank.
If you could point me in a direction, especially with working with the two values, I would really appreciate it.

Comment: You have the code, and need to know what it returns. So run the code, or work it out on paper. Why would you search for that?

Comment: step 1: since `4 * 2` is not `0`, `f(4, 2)` returns `f(3, 1) + f(3, 2)`. Your problem has been reduced to two simpler problems.

Answer (score 1):

If I had to solve this I would create a table for the values of `f`, a fill in small values until you get the answer for `f(4,2)`. This table should also help spot any patterns if you want to figure out a more general patterns.

For starters, its easy tofill in the base case of n = 0 or k = 0:

```
k\n | 0  1  2  3  4
----+----------------
  0 | 1  1  1  1  1
  1 | 1  ?  ?  ?  ?  ...
  2 | 1  ?  ?  ?  ?  
        ...
```

Then, you can start filling out the non-recursive cases. For example, `f(1,1)` is equal to `f(0,0)` + `f(0,1)`

```
k\n | 0  1  2  3  4
----+----------------
  0 | 1  1  1  1  1
  1 | 1  2  ?  ?  ?  ...
  2 | 1  ?  ?  ?  ?  
        ...
```

Comment: If you think an answer solves your problem, you can upvote and/or mark the question as accepted instead of answering with a comment.

Answer (score 0):

In case you're still looking for the actual answer, it's 11:

```
$ python3
Python 3.5.1 (default, Mar 20 2016, 13:59:31)
[GCC 4.2.1 Compatible Apple LLVM 7.0.2 (clang-700.1.81)] on darwin
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> def f(n, k):
...     if k * n == 0:
...         return 1
...     else:
...         return f(n-1, k-1) + f(n-1, k)
...
>>> f(4, 2)
11
```